# Accessing REST API securely from native app before login as cutomer

Tags: rest, oauth, tizen-native-app

I have a native app [android and iOS]. In this, the customer will be able to onboard to the application himself. As part of the onboarding the native app has to consume some backend REST API. How do I securely access the API from the native app?. How do I secure the API? I thought of using OAuth grant type as Client_Credential but understand that we can't securely store the client secret inside native app. Kindly help